# SELECT DISTINCT not working totally on my reports

Tags: sql-server

Here's my stored procedure in SQL Server:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Display_Purchases_PerSupplier] --for getting the sum of distinct rows/values
    @supplier_name varchar (max),
    @month_purc varchar(50),
    @cat varchar(10)
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        (ARTICLES), UNIT, [UNIT PRICE],
        SUM(QTY) * [UNIT PRICE] AS TOT_AMOUNT,
        [PURCHASED FROM], [ADDRESS], TIN, CASHIER,
        SUM(QTY) AS TOTAL
    FROM 
        PURCHASES_SUPPLIER 
    WHERE 
        [PURCHASED FROM] = @supplier_name 
        AND [TRANSACTION MONTH] = @month_purc 
        AND CATEGORY = @cat
    GROUP BY 
        ARTICLES, QTY, UNIT, [UNIT PRICE], AMOUNT, [PURCHASED FROM],
        [ADDRESS], TIN, CASHIER
END
```

My table contains:

```
ARTICLES  | QTY
----------+------
DUMMY       3
TEST        3
DUMMY       2
TEST        3
```

BUT WHEN I RUN REPORT, THE OUTPUT WAS THIS:

```
ARTICLES | QTY
---------+------
DUMMY      3
DUMMY      2
TEST       6
```

What was my mistake in my query? Please help. Thank you

Comment: What would be your expected result? The rows `DUMMY 2` and `DUMMY 3` are indeed distinct.

Comment: It would make sense to link something like an sqlfiddle.

Comment: Format your code.  No one is going to read that.

Comment: Why do you have both DISTINCT and GROUP BY and so many columns in GROUP BY https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp If you aggregate on articles - then    don't include other fields.

Comment: Your query and your expected output are totally different.  Which one do you want???

Comment: what i mean is, i have columns (ITEM column and QTY column) these columns has 4 rows: 1st row (DUMMY,3) 2nd row(TEST,3) 3rd row(DUMMY,2) 4th row(TEST,3)

Comment: then i created my query in sql server and i used SQL DISTINCT but when i run it, the output was (DUMMY,3),(DUMMY,2),(TEST,6)-meaning the SQL DISTINCT did now worked totally because there are still duplicate items. what i want for my output is make duplicate items as one entry and sum up their quantity

Comment: SQL DISTINCT did not worked

Comment: `DISTINCT` with a `GROUP BY` doesnt make a lot of sense. You should already have the distinct results unless you're grouping on more than what is in your `SELECT` (which you are). Why are you grouping on everything?

Comment: i tried to remove the GROUP BY clause from my query but it throws an error:

Comment: here's the error: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Display_Purchases_PerSupplier, Line 10 [Batch Start Line 7]
Column 'PURCHASES_SUPPLIER.ARTICLES' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: i just shortened my number columns guys to ITEM and QTY but what i really want is to make duplicate values on the ARTICLES(ITEM) column a single entry and total its quantity. pls. help. thank you guys

Comment: Select  DISTINCT ARTICLES from PURCHASES_SUPPLIER --> DUMMY and TEST.  But  Select  DISTINCT ARTICLES, QTY from PURCHASES_SUPPLIER -->DUMMY 2  and  DUMMY 3 and  TEST 3.  If you use multiple columns, the query uses the combination of values in all specified columns in the SELECT list to evaluate the uniqueness.

Comment: Does one of your "DUMMY" values have any spaces behind it? Add to your Articles column like this **ARTICLES + "*"** to expose the spaces or trim it to suppress them like this **LTRIM(ARTICLES)**.

Comment: i think its not the spaces because the records for the ARTICLES column is coming from datagridview and transferred to datatable and i checked my table and it has no white spaces. thank you Isaac

Comment: As I said, DUMMY 3 is different from DUMMY 2, each is DISTINCT.  And therefore reported on separate lines.  Distinct uses the combination of values in -->ALL<-- specified columns to evaluate uniqueness.

Comment: Please tell us the result of the following:-- 
Remove DISTINCT, Remove QTY from GroupBy, Remove AMOUNT from GroupBy.
Distinct is not needed here when GroupBy contains all non-aggregate columns.
Qty is aggregated, not a selected alone.  Amount is not selected (and Tot_Amount is aggregated).  And show all of the other columns in the result, at least for DUMMY and TEST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove the **QTY** column from `GROUP BY`.